USB tethering settings keep getting reset after unplugging the smartphone
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and would like to know if it's possible for my "USB ethernet" tethering network settings (namely, marking it as a metered connection, adding custom DNS servers and getting rid of the default non-ascii characters on its name) to actually persist.
Currently, every time I unplug my android device and plug it again, a new profile for "USB ethernet" is created with default settings.
I am on the verge of going crazy with this as I haven't even been able to find anyone else describing this issue after a long googling session. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!
